# Über die Interpretation von »mindestens sechs Monate[n]«

Tags: meaning

Folgende Aufgabe führt aktuell zu heftigen Diskussionen, ob nun *Richtig* oder *Falsch* die korrekte Antwort ist.

Welche Argumente können für welche Seite sprechen?

[image: Aufgabe]

Comment: Welche Argumente gibt es dafür, dass die Antwort "falsch" die korrekte Antwort wäre? Welcher Interpretationsspielraum soll hier bestehen?

Comment: Da ich niemanden Beeinflussen möchte sage ich dazu nichts. Tatsache ist, dass wir in der Firma bereits tagelang darüber streiten.

Comment: Ich habe gerade eine große Menge Kommentare in den [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40872/discussion-on-question-by-l0w-skilled-uber-die-interpretation-von-mindestens-se) verschoben. Bitte nutzt Kommentare nicht für mögliche Antworten auf die Frage und Diskussion derselben. Nutzt bitte Antworten, um Eure Argumentation ausführlich darzulegen, und Kommentare auf Antworten, um die Argumentation anderer zu kritisieren.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Falls es sich um eine juristische Prüfung handelt: Wenn der Sachverhalt zu einer bestimmten Frage nichts aussagt, geht man **immer** vom Regelfall aus (ansonsten droht die gefürchtete "Sachverhaltsquetsche", die man sich als Studierender spätestens im dritten Semester abgewöhnt haben sollte, denn sonst kommt man wahrscheinlich nicht über die Zwischenprüfung hinaus...).

Der Regelfall ist hier eine potentielle Beschäftigungszeit zwischen dem 15. und dem 65. Lebensjahr. Von den 38 Jahren der Beschäftigung im Unternehmen gehen also maximal 10 Jahre ab (als potentiell vor dem 25. Lebensjahr liegend). Die verbleibenden 28 Jahre liegen offensichtlich über den 15 Jahren Unternehmens- oder Betriebszugehörigkeit, die für eine mindestens sechsmonatige Kündigungsfrist hinreichend sind. Damit ist Frau Müllers Argumentation richtig.

EDIT:

Dagegen kann man nicht anführen, dass Frau Müller von "mindestens" spricht. Das geht klar an der Frage vorbei, ob sie *hinsichtlich der Länge ihrer Kündigungsfrist "richtig oder falsch argumentiert".* "Mindestens" ist Teil der Rechtsfolge (Länge der Kündigungsfrist), nicht der Argumentation ("ich bin schon 38 Jahre im Betrieb!"). Wenn das "mindestens" das Ergebnis entwerten würde, *käme es überhaupt nicht auf die Argumentation an*. Dann dürfte man keine der beiden Antworten "richtig" oder "falsch" wählen, da selbst die juristisch beste Argumentation niemals zu einer "mindestens"-Antwort führen dürfte.

Im Gegenschluss wird das noch deutlicher: würde man das Kreuzchen bei "falsch" damit begründen, dass eine Kündigungsfrist immer eine exakte, also keine Mindest-Zeitspanne ist, machte es keinen Unterschied, ob Frau Müller sagt:

> "Ich habe blaue Augen, [deshalb] beträgt meine Kündigungsfrist mindestens sechs Monate!"

, oder ob sie sagt:

> "Meine Betriebszugehörigkeit im Sinne des § 622 BGB beträgt objektiv betrachtet und höchstrichterlich bestätigt mehr als 15 Jahre, [deshalb] beträgt meine Kündigungsfrist mindestens sechs Monate!"

Hingegen wäre nach diesem Ansatz die folgende "Argumentation" richtig (da das Ergebnis exakt zutrifft):

> "Ich habe blaue Augen, [deshalb] beträgt meine Kündigungsfrist exakt sieben Monate!"

In der Original-Aufgabenstellung steht das "deshalb", das ich in den obigen Beispielen eingeklammert habe, *nicht explizit*. Aber in der Fragestellung ist von einer "Argumentation" die Rede, die der Bearbeiter überprüfen und als richtig oder falsch bewerten soll. Ein "Argument" ist laut Wikipedia eine Aussage, die zur Begründung einer anderen Aussage gebraucht wird. Offensichtlich soll die Aussage "Ich arbeite bereits 38 Jahre in diesem Betrieb" als Begründung der Aussage "meine Kündigungsfrist beträgt mindestens sechs Monate" dienen - die erste Aussage ist also das Argument.

EDIT (2):

Nochmals als Klarstellung, weil das auch von sehr intelligenten Leuten missverstanden wurde: Die zitierte Frage zielt **nicht** darauf, zu beurteilen, *ob Frau Müller die Kündigungsfrist mit der Angabe "mindestens sechs Monate" **exakt und korrekt beziffert** hat*. Das hat sie selbstverständlich nicht, da eine Frage nach einer präzisen Fristdauer **niemals** mit der Angabe einer nach oben offenen Zeitspanne richtig beantwortet werden kann, egal wie man argumentiert und die ermittelte Zeitspanne begründet (genauso wenig, wie eine Funktion, die einen einzelnen Integer-Wert liefern soll, keinen Int-Array zurückgeben sollte). Dass es darum nicht geht, kann man eben an der Fallfrage erkennen (auch das lernt man in den Anfangssemestern des juristischen Studiums: Fallfrage beachten!). Es geht darum, zu beurteilen, *ob die Aussage "Betriebszugehörigkeit von 38 Jahren" den Schluss darauf zulässt, dass die exakte Länge der Kündigungsfrist im Bereich "gleich oder größer sechs Monate" liegt*.

Um die Ausgangsfrage komplett zu beantworten: Die richtige Antwort hängt von der Frage ab - die zielt darauf, **ob die *Argumentation* richtig oder falsch ist** (d.h.: nicht darauf, ob das Argumentationsergebnis präzise mit der tatsächlichen Kündigungsfrist übereinstimmt). Wenn man die Frage derart versteht, sehe ich keinerlei Argumente, die für die Variante "falsch" sprechen (und ich habe in der bisherigen Diskussion auch keinerlei Argumente dafür gehört).

Und noch etwas: Das alles hätte man abkürzen können, wenn die "in der Firma seit Tagen geführte Diskussion" - wie von mir erbeten - in der Frage offengelegt worden wäre. Dann hätten Denkfehler schneller identifiziert und korrigiert werden können.

Comment: Aber Frau Müller ist ja schon länger als 20 Jahre in der Firma - damit ist die Kündigungsfrist mindestens 7 Monate lang. Wenn sie also mit genau 6 Monaten rechnet, liegt sie falsch, oder?

Comment: @Mac Erstens ist die Kündigungsfrist – als Tatsache betrachtet – genau sieben Monate, nicht mehr und nicht weniger. Zweitens »rechnet« Frau Müller ja nicht mit »genau sechs Monaten«, sie rechnet mit »**mindestens** sechs Monate[n]«. Das heißt, sie kann davon ausgehen, dass sie auf jeden Fall die nächsten sechs Monate in der Firma noch arbeitet, wenn ihr heute nicht gekündigt worden ist.

Comment: Wollte ich auch gerade sagen... :-)

Answer (score 6):

Im Mathematikunterricht ist die Frage mit »Richtig« zu beantworten; »Falsch« ist mathematisch und logisch falsch, denn 7 > 6.

Juristen wird nachgesagt, dass sie Deutsch und Unverständlisch  sprechen, dass in ihrem Sprachgebrauch also Wörter etwas Anderes bedeuten als im Sprachgebrauch eines jeden Anderen. Daher ist es für mich theoretisch vorstellbar, dass Juristen mit »falsch« antworten, weil »mindestens sechs« ungleich »sieben« ist. Deswegen würde ich trotzdem dem Argument den Vogel zeigen.

Comment: Wenn man diese Aussage als "richtig" bewertet, könnte man Frau M. mit 6-monatiger Frist kündigen. Was gerade nicht zulässig ist.

Comment: @Ingmar Sehe ich nicht so. "mindestens 6 Monate" kann auch ein Jahr sein. Ich sehe keinerlei Aussage über die *tatsächliche* Kündigungsfrist darin.

Comment: Exakt. Frau Müller sagte nicht, dass man sie innerhalb dieser Frist kündigen könnte. Sie hat die **genaue Dauer der Kündigungsfrist offengelassen** und nur die **Untergrenze des Bereichs** angegeben, **innerhalb dessen** ihrer Meinung nach die zutreffende Kündigungsfrist liegt. Eine Frist von sieben Monaten liegt im Bereich >= 6 Monate.

Answer (score 2):

Die Ursache der Meinungsverschiedenheiten liegt vermutlich darin begründet, dass sich in dem Kontext drei mögliche Einschränkungen variabler Zeiten verstecken:

- Das Wort *Frist,* das üblicherweise eine Höchstdauer bezeichnet. Im Gegensatz dazu bezeichnet *Kündigungsfrist* aber weder eine Höchst- noch eine Mindestdauer, sondern ein feste Dauer, nämlich diejenige zwischen Kündigungsausstellung und dem tatsächlichen Ende des Beschäftigungsverhältnisses.
- Im Geiste des § 622 BGB, dessen Sinn es ist Arbeitnehmer und -geber vor einem plötzlichen Ende von Beschäftigungsverhältnissen zu schützen. In diesem Geiste wäre ggf. naiv zu erwarten, dass der Paragraph minimale Kündigungsfristen vorschreibt – was er aber nicht tut.
- Im Wort *mindestens.*

Werden diese Einschränkungen oder vermeintlichen Einschränkungen vermengt, entstehen naturgemäß Unklarheiten.

Richtig ist aber:

- Der Zeitpunkt zwischen Ausstellung der Kündigung und Ende des Beschäftigungsverhältnisses (Kündigungsfrist) ist zu einem gegebenen Zeitpunkt und für ein gegebenes Arbeitsverhältnis eine Zeitspanne von fester Dauer (zumindest wenn wie hier keine weiteren Sonderregeln greifen). Ist diese Dauer geklärt, gibt es keinen Spielraum, auf den sich *mindestens* beziehen kann. Wenn Frau Müller sich der gesetzlichen Lage und ihres Lebenslaufs völlig bewusst ist, hat sie also keinen Grund, das Wort *mindestens* in den Mund zu nehmen.
- Also besteht der einzige Spielraum, auf den das Wort *mindestens* anspielen kann, in der Frage, wie Frau Müllers gesetzliche Situation bestellt ist, also welche Kündigungsfrist sie eigentlich hat. Wenn sich Frau Müller zum Beispiel im Unklaren über die gesetzliche Lage ist, könnte sie sagen:

  > Ich müsste nachschlagen, wie lange meine Kündigungsfrist jetzt ist, aber da sie , muss sie jetzt mindestens sechs Monate sein, da dies ihre Dauer vor ein paar Jahren war, als ich sie nachgeschlagen habe, und sie nicht kürzer werden kann.

  Außerdem bezieht sich *mindestens* klar auf das Wort *Frist,* und nicht auf irgendwelche durch die Frist impliziten Zeitdauern.

**Selbst wenn** das Wort *Kündigungsfrist* nur eine Mindestdauer o. Ä. (statt einer festen Zeitspanne) bezeichnen würde, wäre die Aussage richtig, da diese Offenheit bereits in dem Wort *Kündigungsfrist* abgedeckt wäre. Man vergleiche mit folgendem Satz:

> Die Frist zum Nachreichen des Bescheids beträgt sechs Monate.

Hier beinhaltet das Wort *Frist* bereits eine Höchstdauer – niemand würde auf die Idee kommen, dass der Bescheid nach **genau** sechs Monaten eingereicht werden muss. Die Einschränkung *höchstens* hinzuzufügen ergibt daher nur Sinn, wenn sich der Sprecher unsicher über die Dauer der Frist ist. Dies wird insbesondere deutlich, wenn man *mindestens* statt *höchstens* verwendet:

> Die Frist zum Nachreichen des Bescheids beträgt mindestens sechs Monate. (Sie brauchen sich also in keinem Fall zu beeilen.)

Hier würde auch niemand auf die Idee kommen, dass vor Einreichung des Bescheids eine bestimmte Frist verstreichen **müsste**.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an obvious, and a not-so-obvious answer to the question. It depends a bit on whether the purpose of the question is language skills (assumed) or logic...

Obvious: Frau Müller is with the company for more than 15 years (that is the pre-condition for "at least 6 months", actually, it could also be "7 months", but that is covered by the "mindestens"), so the answer would be "true". I guess that is the "right" and intended answer.

Not-so-obvious (and, admittedly, logical nit-picking): She could have been hired as a 1-year-old-baby (which is kind of improbable, but possible - She could have been "working part-time" as a model for baby clothing, whatever). In this case, we'd have to deduct 24 years from the 38, because they "count" only once you are over 25. In this case she'd be with the company for 14 years after 25, so her termination conditions would say "5 months".

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.

The question is not about the age.

Comment: Also: In Germany youre allowed to work when you are 15 years old. That would mean, since it starts with 25 years, she has atleast been 23 years in the company.

Comment: The "model" example was chosen on purpose - For jobs like that you can get an exemption from the "Jugendamt"

Answer (score 1):

Die Antwort ist »Richtig« und *mindestens* ist auch richtig in dem Zusammenhang, denn die Kündigungsfrist kann ja vom Arbeitgeber aus auch länger gewählt werden. Das Gesetz gibt ja nur Untergrenzen vor.

Und es kann auch sein, dass Frau Müller nicht die Grenze von 25 Jahren kennt, also unsicher ist, ob 6 oder 7 Monate Frist einzuhalten sind. In dem Fall ist *mindestens* auch richtig eingesetzt.

Für den Leser ist *mindestens* als Angabe auch richtig, da der Leser nicht das Eintrittsalter kennt.

Comment: Die 25 Jahr-Grenze ist hier aber vollkommen irrelevant. Seit Frau Müllers 25. Geburtstag müssten ja sonst weniger als 20 Jahre vergangen sein - bei 38 Jahren Betriebszugehörigkeit hieße das, sie wäre seit dem **7.** Lebensjahr beschäftigt - ein bißchen zu früh dafür.

Comment: *die Kündigungsfrist kann ja vom Arbeitgeber aus auch länger gewählt werden. Das Gesetz gibt ja nur Untergrenzen vor.* – Das ist falsch, siehe [§ 622 (2), BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__622.html).

Comment: Außerdem könnte für Dich von Interesse sein: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)